# Permanent storage of transaction Tag and signatureMessageFragment?

Tags: transaction, tangle

I am not able to find a clear answer.
I would like to ask whether the Transaction Tag and signatureMessageFragment for Non-0 transactions are purged during each snapshot, or not?
If either of them is purged, is there a way to prevent that?
Many thanks.

EDIT: Someone marked this as duplicate and referred me to another thread. Said thread has zero information about how to make the Transaction Tag and signatureMessageFragment stay permanently. 
From all the vague bits of info here are elsewhere, I assume that normally the Transaction Tag and signatureMessageFragment are purged during a snapshop. It may be possible to retain them on your own node. How to configure such node may or may not be another question.

Comment: The suggest duplicate isn't very explicit regarding snapshot and don't explain/suggest any way to prevent lost of data after snapshots